# Animating "sliding" in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, core-animation, nsoutlineview

I've done a fair amount of Googling, but still haven't find any proper solution for animating the expansion of NSOutlineView.  I'm trying to mimic a "sliding" animation when expanding/collapsing rows.  Anyone know a good strategy for attempting this?

Animating this:

}} Folder 1

To expand and look like this:

}} Folder 1

}}}}} Item 1

}}}}} Item 2

}}}}} Item 3

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project: [TLAnimatingOutlineview](http://code.google.com/p/tlanimatingoutlineview/)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple, and you don’t need third-party libraries. Instead of calling the `expandItem:` / `collapseItem:` directly on your `NSOutlineView` instance, you pass them to the `animator` proxy object.

```m
NSOutline *outlineView = ...;
id item = ...;
[[outlineView animator] collapseItem:item];
```

Also note that you can expand/collapse all the cells at once by passing a `nil` item.

Documentation: [NSAnimatablePropertyContainer Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSAnimatablePropertyContainer_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html)